# Bash script for Logrotate can't start in crontab

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron, logrotate

i have a simple bash script for execute a `logrotate` command which is the follow command:

```bsh
sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/logfile
```

When i set the bash script into crontab the script didn't execute, but when i run script manually it's working.

This is the line in crontab:

```bsh
* * * * * /home/plamen/test/demo.sh
```

I've tried also the following in cron and still not working.

```bsh
root /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/logfile
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Hi, Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Cron runs with a different set of environment variables to those in use when you run a script in a terminal. You need to load your environment near the start of the script. There are plenty of answered questions on here about how to do that.

Comment: Dont put SOLVED in  question header .... make an answer and accept that when possible.

Answer (score 0):

The files in `/etc/logrotate.d/` are handled by the service `logrotate.service` so at all you don't need rotating the logs via `crontab`.

However if you want to rotate some logs now, you need to use the option `--force` (or `-f`):

```bsh
logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/your-logrotate-conf
```

Within `crontab` (in this count within scripts triggered by it), as you know, must be used full paths also the `logrotate` command must be executed as root (or by `sudo`), so you can place your directive in the root's crontab. You can edit it by the command `sudo crontab -e` and the relevant line should look like:

```bsh
* * * * * /home/plamen/test/demo.sh >> /tmp/crontab.demo.sh.log 2>&1
```

In this case you do not need to specify the user `root` because this is its personal `crontab`.

Another option is to place the directive into `/etc/crontab` which is the systemwide `crontab` (or you can create a dedicated file `/etc/cron.d/my-app-crontab`) where you must specify the user:

```bsh
* * * * * root /home/plamen/test/demo.sh >> /tmp/crontab.demo.sh.log 2>&1
```

**Note:** In the above examples is added the redirection `>> /tmp/crontab.demo.sh.log 2>&1` which will create a logfile in order to debug the process.

Answer (score 0):

It's work but which a different way.

1. I made a file in /home/plamen/test/logrotate.conf:

   ```
   logrotate /home/plamen/test/logrotate.conf --state /home/plamen/test/logrotate-state --verbose
   ```
2. Or in crontab:

   ```
   logrotate /home/plamen/test/logrotate.conf --state /home/plamen/test/logrotate-state --verbose
   ```